# Allow command on "if statement" being satisfied

Tags: android

I currently have a command that will allow the user to proceed to the next page if a button is clicked, this button has a feature `android:onClick="advancenext"` which I have defined in the `.java` file to be the following

```
public void advancenext (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this, Prompt2.class);
    Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

However, I only want the user to call `advancenext` if a variable `i` is greater than 5. This is what I tried

```
if (i>5) {
    public void advancenext (View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this, Prompt2.class);
            Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the app, I can still advance even though i is not greater than 5. Does anyone know how to fix this, or better restrict `advancenext` in a different way?

**EDIT** Thanks for the great answers, but I encountered a different error when I changed my statement. When I try:

```
            public void advancenext (View view) {
                if (i>5) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this, Prompt2.class);
                    Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

I get the errors `Syntax error on token "(", ; expected` and `Syntax error on token ")", ; expected` around the `(` and `)` of `(View view)`.

**EDIT dos** Here's my full code

```
public class Prompt1 extends Activity {

    int i; //Variable i stores the touch number
    float[] X, Y;  //Array that will store the touchpoints
    int ultscore1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prompt1);

        i=1;

        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

                i++; //increasing i value

                public void advancenext (View view) {
                    if (i>5) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this,     Prompt2.class);
                        Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                }               
                return true;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Where is your code? Is it inside of `onCreate()` or another method? If so, it needs to go outside of a method just like any other function would be.

Comment: Just because this seems to be a problem with format, why don't you post your code for the entire class so we can see where you are missing your parentheses or something.

Comment: I'm thinking it MUST have been.  Otherwise the IF statement would have given a compile error ahead of time.

Comment: put `advancenext ` function outside `setOnTouchListener` and try..

Comment: @Lal I moved it outside of the onTouchListener but I still got the same error

Comment: check my answer...replace your code like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this

```
public class Prompt1 extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

int i; //Variable i stores the touch number
float[] X, Y;  //Array that will store the touchpoints
int ultscore1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prompt1);

    i=1;

    touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    i++; //increasing i value
    advancenext(v);
    return true;
} 

public void advancenext (View view) {
    if (i>5) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this,     Prompt2.class);
        Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

This allows your class to directly handle the touch event (and any other touch events for views contained in the classes set content view) by just adding the on touch listener to the view. You can handle the incrementing of your variable `i` in onTouch like you were and call your advancenext method with the view passed to onTouch. The method, advancenext, could very easily have its functionality moved to onTouch, that is

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    i++; //increasing i value
    if (i>5) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this,     Prompt2.class);
        Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

But moving the functionality out of onTouch into it's own method will allow you to use advancenext with other io events (like onClick).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But when I tried this, I get a different error, please see my edit in the question.

Comment: missing return statement for onTouch()

Comment: @Lal blah been coding too much today

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate your if statement inside your function. Be sure you have access to `i` variable.

```
public void advancenext(View view) {
    if (i>5) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this, Prompt2.class);
         Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But when I tried this, I get a different error, please see my edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You've got your statement backwards:

```
public void advancenext (View view) {
    if (i>5) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Prompt1.this, Prompt2.class);
        Prompt1.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

You should call your `onClick()` function no matter what, THEN check the condition.  The way you have it now, you are ignoring the `if` statement completely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But when I tried this, I get a different error, please see my edit in the question.